# Asterisk times out and terminates connection after 6400ms due to 'no response'

Tags: asterisk, sip, freepbx

I have a SIP trunk set up with Twilio for outbound calls. Twilio-FreePBX and then my test device is the simple X-Lite from CounterPath.

I can make an outgoing call from X-Lite. My cell phone rings and I can pick up. But that's it, there is no audio transmitted and the call hangs up on it's own after a handful of seconds.

This is the error I receive from the Asterisk log inside my FreePBX server:

```
[2017-02-17 14:41:46] WARNING[1996] chan_sip.c: Retransmission timeout reached     on transmission 83369MWU3MmY5MWZiZWZkODJmYjc3ZWEzMWI5ZmQzMTQ1NWQ for seqno 2   (Critical Response) -- See https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/SIP+Retransmissions
Packet timed out after 6400ms with no response
[2017-02-17 14:41:46] WARNING[1996] chan_sip.c: Hanging up call 83369MWU3MmY5MWZiZWZkODJmYjc3ZWEzMWI5ZmQzMTQ1NWQ - no reply to our critical packet (see https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/SIP+Retransmissions).
```

The call is routing through my Twilio account, I can see it in the logs there. It registers as `complete`.

I've turned the FreePBX firewall on and added trusted IP's
[image]

The full Asterisk debug log:

```
<------------->
[2017-02-17 15:18:58] VERBOSE[1996] chan_sip.c: --- (12 headers 12 lines) ---
[2017-02-17 15:18:58] VERBOSE[1996][C-00000004] chan_sip.c: Found RTP audio format 0
[2017-02-17 15:18:58] VERBOSE[1996][C-00000004] chan_sip.c: Found RTP audio format 101
[2017-02-17 15:18:58] VERBOSE[1996][C-00000004] chan_sip.c: Found audio description format PCMU for ID 0
[2017-02-17 15:18:58] VERBOSE[1996][C-00000004] chan_sip.c: Found audio description format telephone-event for ID 101
[2017-02-17 15:18:58] VERBOSE[1996][C-00000004] chan_sip.c: Capabilities: us - (ulaw|alaw|gsm|g726), peer - audio=(ulaw)/video=(nothing)/text=(nothing), combined - (ulaw)
[2017-02-17 15:18:58] VERBOSE[1996][C-00000004] chan_sip.c: Non-codec capabilities (dtmf): us - 0x1 (telephone-event|), peer - 0x1 (telephone-event|), combined - 0x1 (telephone-event|)
[2017-02-17 15:18:58] VERBOSE[1996][C-00000004] chan_sip.c: Peer audio RTP is at port 54.172.61.111:12510
[2017-02-17 15:18:58] VERBOSE[1996][C-00000004] sip/route.c: sip_route_dump: route/path hop: <sip:54.172.60.2:5060;lr;ftag=as7484893d;twnat=sip:52.90.124.243:5060>
[2017-02-17 15:18:58] VERBOSE[1996][C-00000004] chan_sip.c: Transmitting (NAT) to 54.172.60.2:5060:
ACK sip:172.18.7.119:5060 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 172.**.**.***:5060;branch=z9hG4bK2b6c05a0;rport
Route: <sip:54.172.60.2:5060;lr;ftag=as7484893d;twnat=sip:52.90.124.243:5060>
Max-Forwards: 70
From: <sip:PHIL@172.**.**.***>;tag=as7484893d
To: <sip:+18566492240@********.pstn.twilio.com>;tag=77864250_6772d868_655d5c53-0b14-4aa5-8bd5-d8f83501d26c
Contact: <sip:PHIL@172.**.**.***:5060>
Call-ID: 664a272c08f7af0543b2bac950391d32@172.**.**.***:5060
CSeq: 103 ACK
User-Agent: FPBX-13.0.190.7(13.12.2)
Content-Length: 0


---
[2017-02-17 15:18:58] VERBOSE[8613][C-00000004] app_dial.c: SIP/Twilio Trunk-00000009 answered SIP/808-00000008
[2017-02-17 15:18:58] VERBOSE[8613][C-00000004] chan_sip.c: Audio is at 12824
[2017-02-17 15:18:58] VERBOSE[8613][C-00000004] chan_sip.c: Adding codec ulaw to SDP
[2017-02-17 15:18:58] VERBOSE[8613][C-00000004] chan_sip.c: Adding codec alaw to SDP
[2017-02-17 15:18:58] VERBOSE[8613][C-00000004] chan_sip.c: Adding non-codec 0x1 (telephone-event) to SDP
[2017-02-17 15:18:58] VERBOSE[8613][C-00000004] chan_sip.c:
<--- Reliably Transmitting (NAT) to 73.81.116.96:35304 --->
SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 73.81.116.96:35304;branch=z9hG4bK-524287-1---d5cf0232413c0269;received=73.81.116.96;rport=35304
From: "Phil"<sip:808@52.90.124.243>;tag=82678409
To: <sip:+18566492240@52.90.124.243>;tag=as08c320c9
Call-ID: 83369ZWQ2OTI2MjRkNGE3MTdlYmM5MjYxM2Q0ZDIwOWVhYTM
CSeq: 2 INVITE
Server: FPBX-13.0.190.7(13.12.2)
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH, MESSAGE
Supported: replaces, timer
Contact: <sip:+18566492240@172.**.**.***:5060>
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length: 278

v=0
o=root 1504626483 1504626483 IN IP4 172.**.**.***
s=Asterisk PBX 13.12.2
c=IN IP4 172.**.**.***
t=0 0
m=audio 12824 RTP/AVP 0 8 101
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:101 0-16
a=ptime:20
a=maxptime:150
a=sendrecv

<------------>
[2017-02-17 15:18:58] VERBOSE[8637][C-00000004] bridge_channel.c: Channel SIP/Twilio Trunk-00000009 joined 'simple_bridge' basic-bridge <e035a287-8fa3-4291-a3ad-927bca1407e0>
[2017-02-17 15:18:58] VERBOSE[8613][C-00000004] bridge_channel.c: Channel SIP/808-00000008 joined 'simple_bridge' basic-bridge <e035a287-8fa3-4291-a3ad-927bca1407e0>
[2017-02-17 15:18:58] VERBOSE[1996] chan_sip.c: Retransmitting #1 (NAT) to 73.81.116.96:35304:
SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 73.81.116.96:35304;branch=z9hG4bK-524287-1---d5cf0232413c0269;received=73.81.116.96;rport=35304
From: "Phil"<sip:808@52.90.124.243>;tag=82678409
To: <sip:+18566492240@52.90.124.243>;tag=as08c320c9
Call-ID: 83369ZWQ2OTI2MjRkNGE3MTdlYmM5MjYxM2Q0ZDIwOWVhYTM
CSeq: 2 INVITE
Server: FPBX-13.0.190.7(13.12.2)
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH, MESSAGE
Supported: replaces, timer
Contact: <sip:+18566492240@172.**.**.***:5060>
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length: 278

v=0
o=root 1504626483 1504626483 IN IP4 172.**.**.***
s=Asterisk PBX 13.12.2
c=IN IP4 172.**.**.***
t=0 0
m=audio 12824 RTP/AVP 0 8 101
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:101 0-16
a=ptime:20
a=maxptime:150
a=sendrecv
```

The `Retransmitting` goes on for 6 tries before killing the connection.

Any help would be great. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like RTP is being sent to the wrong place.  Ensure your firewall is open, that your public interface is set in SIP.conf and that NAT is enabled if required.

Comment: what is `Twilio-FreePBX`?